# Masstransit with proxy

Tags: proxy, rabbitmq, masstransit

Have not found that neither in documentation nor here.

Is there any possibility to add proxy for a masstransit? For example for rabbitmq

I expected to have something like that:

```
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
            {
                x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
                        {
                            cfg.Host(_connectionString);
                            cfg.OverrideDefaultBusEndpointQueueName(nameof(IBus));
                            cfg.AddProxy(new WebProxy()...)
                        });
            });
```

but cannot find even a hint of proxy configs

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any sort of proxy configuration for MassTransit, particularly not for RabbitMQ. That is something you'd have to setup separately, using ssh or some other tunneling solution.

Comment: Can I contribute to Masstransit to add proxy configs at least for ASB? At ConnectionFactory we can configure web proxy, the only thing is to be able to pass it from configs. If yes, how long could the whole process take aprox?